# Как закрыть доступ к ко всем каналам кроме одной discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было закрыть доступ (сделать приватными) текстовые каналы кроме одного? в python через библиотеку discord. И как сделать наоборот?, чтобы всё выполнялось командой

Comment: А не проще ли будет создать роль и выдавать её или снимать при вписании команды?

Comment: хм... наверно это реально будет проще

Comment: Вам помочь с этим?

Comment: если можете, то да))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу проблему можно решить в более лёгкой форме. Просто создайте роль через дискорд, в каналах выставьте настройки. А через бота сделайте выдачу роли:

```
@client.command()
async def arole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, role: discord.Role): #Создаём функцию
    await ctx.message.delete() #Можно удалить отправленное сообщение пользователем
    await member.add_roles(role) #Добавляем роль через упоминание. БЕЗ НЕГО РАБОТАТЬ НЕ БУДЕТ. Чтобы сделать выдачу роли без упоминания - надо указать айди. Для этого в дискорде нужно к упоминанию роли добавить \ и отправить. Например: \@Роль. Мы получили айди

    #Отправка. Никак не влияет на выдачу роли. Можно убрать эмбед и сделать просто сообщение, а можно вообще не делать.
    await member.send(f"Вам выдали роль под названием: {role}. Произошло это на этом сервере: {ctx.guild.name}")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="╔=====================================╗", colour=discord.Color.greyple(),
                          description=f"{member.mention} получил следующую роль: {role}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed) #Отправка сообщения
```

Этот код раотает на эту команду: `!arole @member @role`. Если же вы `await member.add_roles(role)` заменили на `await member.add_roles(айди)` и убрали `role: discord.Role`, то просто `!arole @member`. Обратите внимание - знак ! - это мой префикс, у вас он может быть другой.

Если я помог вам - отметьте ответ верным. Если нет - пишите в комментарии, помогу

Comment: Спасиб)) вы мне очень помогли <:

Comment: Здрасте, а можно сделать так, чтобы пользователь написал команду, и ему выдалась роль?)

Comment: @cat00mem конечно можно. Однако это другой вопрос